# ¿Cómo leer los datos pasados en curl desde un interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

Estoy trabajando en un micro-servicio en el que tengo que guardar en el log las peticiones que se han hecho, así como algunos valores en particular.

Para ello he creado un interceptor que intercepta y maneja las peticiones que se hacen al servidor, y que guarda en el log las cabeceras con sus valores, el método usado y el path del servicio que se llamó. Éste es mi código:

```
package com.compania.equipo.proyecto.configuration

import com.compania.equipo.proyecto.miClase
import com.google.gson.Gson
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView

@Component
class RequestInterceptor : HandlerInterceptor {

  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestInterceptor::class.java)

  override fun preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, dataObject: Any) : Boolean {
    val headerMap = request.headerNames.toList().map { it to request.getHeader(it) }.toMap()
    log.info("Request Received.")
    log.info("Method: " + request.method)
    log.info("Path: " + request.servletPath)
    log.info("Headers: " + headerMap.toString())

    return true
  }

  override fun postHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, dataObject: Any, model: ModelAndView?) {
    log.info("Request Processed.")
  }

  override fun afterCompletion(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, dataObject: Any, e: Exception?) {
    log.info("Request Completed.")
  }
}
```

Entonces si hago una petición como la siguiente:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4568/miServicio -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
     "id" : 123,
     "suma" : 456,
     "valor" : 789
 }'
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
Request Received.
Method: POST
Path: /miServicio
Headers: {host=localhost:4568, user-agent=curl/7.54.0, accept=*/*, content-type=application/json, content-length=107}
Request Processed.
Request Completed.
```

Y ahora me han pedido que además también haga logging de los datos (p.e. en el comando curl anterior sería `{ "id" : 123, "suma" : 456, "valor" : 789 }`). He intentado poniendo este código en el `preHandle`:

```
val reader = request.reader
val gson = Gson()
val requestdata = gson.fromJson<Any>(reader, miClase::class.java)
log.info(requestdata.toString())
```

esa parte del código funciona, pero acto seguido recibo el siguiente mensaje de error y termina mi aplicación:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReader() has already been called for this request] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReader() has already been called for this request

Esto parece que ocurre porque `getReader` sólo se puede llamar una vez, y lo estaría llamando en el `preHandle` y luego automáticamente en el controlador del servicio.

Después de ver los [comentarios de SJuan76](http://#comment262329_140401), intenté usar el `inputStream` en lugar de el `reader`, leyendo los bytes del `inputStream` y poniéndolos en una cadena:

```
val requestReader = request.inputStream.readBytes()
val requestBody = String(requestReader)
log.info(requestBody)
```

Ya no me sale el error anterior, y veo los datos en el log, pero me encuentro que ahora me da fallo en el controlador:

> Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:

Parece que porque como los datos ya han sido leídos, ya no están en el stream y no se pueden leer de nuevo en el controlador.

Como alternativa, de momento lo he quitado del `preHandle` y hago el log en el controlador sin problemas, pero me gustaría saber si hay algún modo de leer los datos pasados en el curl directamente en el `preHandle` para tener todo el logging en un mismo sitio (el interceptor).

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el controlador del servicio está llamando a `getReader()`? Según la documentación de `HttpServletRequest`, la excepción se lanza si combinas llamadas a `getReader()` y `getInputStream()`, no si llamas múltiples veces a solo uno de ellos.

Comment: En todo caso, aunque el punto de arriba sea correcto, no tengo claro si `getInputStream` devuelve cada vez un `InputStream` diferente o la misma instancia. En este último caso, aunque desapareciera la excepción, es muy posible que la solución no te sirviera (ya que el contenido del `InputStream` ya habría sido consumido al llegar al controlador).

Comment: @SJuan76 he intentado leyendo el `InputStream` y entonces puedo leer el body del request pero entonces me da otro fallo porque parece que el body no llega al controlador. Voy a actualizar la pregunta con la información adicional.

Comment: Entonces es lo que apuntaba en el segundo comentario; parece que el `HttpServletRequest` no "almacena" lo que le llega en el cuerpo de la petición, sino que simplemente te proporciona un acceso al stream de datos desde la conexión TCP; la comunicación por la red se realiza según vas consumiendo bytes del `InputStream`/`Reader`...